# Detect end of TextView with ScrollingMovementMethod

Tags: android

I have a long textview that I am displaying inside of a Cardview. I've added ScrollingMovementMethod() so that the user can scroll the textview.

I want to be able to detect when a user has reached the end of the textview/scroll. I've seen examples for Scrolllview but none for TextView with ScrollingMovementMethod

Comment: Ever found out how to get this ?